# Easy probability question

Tags: probability

I have question on probability  :

- $H$ occurs  $\implies$ $C$ occurs
- $H$ does not occur   $\implies$ $C$ can occur or cannot
- if i want to compute $P(H|C)=\dfrac{P(H).P(C|H)}{P(C)}$ does $P(C|H)=1$ ? If yes then $P(H|C)=\dfrac{P(H)}{P(H)+P(H^c)(1-P(C))}$
  ?

Comment: It seems strange to call this a "probability" problem!  The only possible probabilities are "0" and "1"- "false" and "true" so I would consider this a logic problem. "If H is true then C is true is the same as "if C is false the H is false".  Similarly "If C is true then H is true" is the same as "If H if false the C is false". The two together give "H is true if and only if C is true"  Both P(H|C) and P(C|H) are 1.

Comment: If i say C can occur even if H was false would that be a different question?

Answer (score 2):

If we interpret $H \implies C$ as $H \subseteq C$, then $H \cap C = H$ so
$$P(H \vert C) = \frac{P(H \cap C)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(H)}{P(C)} \le 1$$
while
$$P(C \vert H) = \frac{P(H \cap C)}{P(H)} = \frac{P(H)}{P(H)} = 1$$

Comment: yes this is it i think thank you that implie sign mean that H is in C

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the first question, Yes, $P(C|H)=1$.

In answer to the second question, No, $P(C)\not=P(H)+P(H^c)(1-P(C))$ in general.  For example, suppose you roll a die twice.  Let $H$ be the event that the sum of the two rolls is $11$, and let $C$ be the event that the first roll is a $5$ or a $6$.  It's clear that if $H$ occurs then $C$ occurs (how can the sum be $11$ if the first roll is $4$ or less?).  And it's easy to see that $P(H)={1\over18}$ and $P(C)={1\over3}$, and then check that

$$P(H)+P(H^c)(1-P(C))={1\over18}+{17\over18}(1-{1\over3})={37\over54}\not={1\over3}=P(C)$$